# MongoDB slice with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am using Codeigniter and Alex Bilbie's great MongoDB library. I need to do pagination
on sub documents. From what I read the function to use is slice but there seems to be no
built in support for this in Alex´s library. Or is there?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: You'd be much quicker asking @alexbilbie on Twitter. I'll poke him for you :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have a go implementing the $slice operator in the library for you later today.

I'll update this (and your message on Github) when it's in and tested.

Alex